# Why is the proof not right ? Every positive integer can be written as a product of primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Here is my proof (not from the textbook). Please let me know if it is wrong.

```
PROOF:
```

I prove by contradiction i.e. I assume N as smallest +ve integer which has non-prime factor p and a prime factor q

N = p * q

p = N\q

from our assumptions,
p is an integer, it is not prime and it is expressed as a fraction of 2 integers.

This is a contradiction (when you substitute p as the new N). Therefore, p is a prime and hence N is a product of primes.

Comment: I can't follow your logic.  $8=2\times 4$ has a prime factor, $2$, and a non-prime factor, $4$.  That would be the smallest such.  So what?

Comment: what about p=1...

Comment: @lulu, See by induction, you can substitute p as the new N and claim the contradiction a few levels down, no ?

Comment: Not following.  I gave you the least $N$ of the form you wanted.  It exists, it is $N=8$.  How do you plan on getting a contradiction out of that?

Comment: To clarify the issue for yourself, start with $N=8$.  In your notation that makes $p=4,q=2$.  You then direct your readers to consider $p=4=\frac Nq=\frac 82$.  You then assure us that this is impossible, but why would that be?  It is surely true that $4=\frac 82$.  Where is the contradiction?

Comment: @lulu, then you start with p as the new N. i.e in the next iteration,
N = p * q
4 = 2 * 2
p = 4/2 
i.e. p is an integer, a non-prime and a fraction of 2 integers.

then in the next iteration: N is now 2
N = p * q
2 = 1 * 2
p = 2 / 2
i.e. p is an integer, a non-prime and a fraction of 2 integers
this is a contradiction because p (in this case 1) is a prime number.
Hence you go all the way up and N only has prime factors.

Comment: That is not what you say at all, you claim to have shown that $p$, $4$ in this case, is prime which it is not.  Maybe you think you are contradicting the minimality of $N$ which you are not.  $4$ is not of the form you specify.  Sorry, I think your proof is misconceived.  I advise starting over.

Comment: We just cross-posted, can you check the logic there ?

Comment: As a hint toward the usual proof:  Suppose the theorem is false and let $N$ be the smallest counterexample.  Now derive a contradiction from that.

Comment: The proof that you wrote in the post is incorrect, for the reasons I said.  Your last comment is silly...I gave you an explicit $N$!   There is no contradiction to be derived from the existence of $8$.  Just ask yourself, how could playing some trivial game with the factors of $8$ possibly prove something that held for all natural numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70086/discussion-between-new-student-and-lulu).

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to discuss this further.  I have explained the flaw in your argument and provided a hint toward the standard proof.  Take a look at the hint.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is incorrect because you are claiming to derive a contradiction from $p$ not being a fraction of two integers. However, $6=\frac{12}{2}$ is not prime, it has prime denominator, and it is a fraction of two integers, so this isn't actually a contradiction. (Here $p=6$, $q=2$, and $N=12$).

Answer (score 0):

First take into account that $1$ is a positive integer that cannot be expressed as a product of primes.

Then, following that, we have that no prime number can be expressed as a product of primes, since the only way to facotr a prime $p$ is $p= p \times 1 = p \times 1 \times 1...$. It's always either a product of 1 prime o a prime and any amount of $1$'s.

So what you might want to prove is: Every positive number bigger than $1$ can be expressed as a product of 1 or more primes

This can be written as $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists \{p_1,p_2,...,p_m\}: n = p_1 p_2  ... p_m$$ where $p_i \le p_{i+1} \ \ \ \forall 1 \le i \le m -1 $

Which is true and known as the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic

Also, this factorization is unique

I'll save this anwer and I'll be back in about an hour if you want me to prove this (or just look up the proof since it's everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

The first flaw is that, by def'n, $1$ is not prime so you should state and prove that if $1<n\in \Bbb N$ then $n$ is a product of primes.

The second flaw is assuming that if $1<n\in \Bbb N$ then $n$ has a prime factor $q.$ Although this is true, it ought to be proven: Let $q$ be the smallest (positive integer) factor of $n$ that's greater than $1.$ So $n=pq$ with $p\in \Bbb N.$ Then $q$ is prime. For, if not, then $q=q'q''$  where $q',q'' \in \Bbb N$ with $q'>1<q'',$ but then $q'$ is a factor of n (because $n=q'\cdot pq''),$ but $1<q'<q,$ a contradiction.

After that part, I disagree with some of the other comments and say you are correct, although it should be presented with more detail, as follows: Suppose (by contradiction) there is a least $n\in \Bbb N$ with $n>1$ where $n$ is not prime and not a product of primes  Then $n=pq$ where $1<p\in \Bbb N$ and $q$ is prime. Since $p<n,$ either $p$ is prime, or (by the minimality of $n$) $p$ is a product  of primes, but in either case this makes $n=pq$ a product of primes.

You can avoid proving that if $1<n\in \Bbb N$ then $n$ has a prime factor $q,$ and obtain that as a corollary to the main result, as follows: Suppose (by ccontradiction) there is a least $n\in \Bbb N$ with $n>1$ where $n$ is not prime and $n$ is not a product of primes. Then $n=ab$ where $a,b \in \Bbb N$ and $a>1<b.$ Since $a<n>b,$ the minimality of $n$ implies that each of $a,b$ is either prime or a product of primes, but then $n=ab$ is a product of primes.